# Changing image using jquery not in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have 3 process so at the end of each process I need to change the image of loading gif to tick mark gif. But the function 1 end the image doesn't change, but only after end of second function. I think the executing is not line by line.

Here is a snippet (area to focus is marked)

```
eel.process1()(function(ret){
    if (ret == 1){
        $('#image1').attr('src', './img/tick.gif');   <------ This take change only with image 2 change (ISSUE)
        $('#P1').css('color' , 'red');             <------ This changes real time but not the image above
        eel.process2()(function(ret){
            if(ret == 1){
                $("#image2").attr("src","./img/tick.gif");  <------ This changes right when the process 2 return value is arrived
                $('#P2').css('color' , 'red');       <----- This, image2 and image1 changes all at the same time only. But I need image 1 to change before image 2 changes.
                eel.process3()(function(ret){
                    if(ret == 1)
                    {
                        $("#image3").attr("src","./img/tick.gif");   <------this changes correct time
                    } 
                    else{
                        $('#P3').text(ret);
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                $('#P2').text(ret);
            }
        })
    }
    else {
                    $('#P1').text(ret);
        }
})
```

So the issue I have is that the #image1 is not changed right away. What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**
As I was able to solve this, I added the tick mark in html and made its `visibility = hidden` in css. I correctly overlayed this above the loading image for process 1 and instead of changing the `src` I changed the visibility of tick mark for process 1.

But this time the `image2` had the issue. It only changed along with `image3` even though the tick image was already inserted to html. I think I have to overlay everthing!! Whats going wrong. The image is only 4 kb. Its on a local server.

Edit: Here is the HTML part:

```
<div class="waitscreen">
            <img src="./img/pre-loader.gif" id="mainload" width="200">
            <div class="progress">
                <img src="./img/loading.gif" id="image1" width="25px"><span id="P1">Reading File</span><br>
                <img src="./img/loading.gif" id="image2" width="25px"><span id="P2">Formatting Output</span><br>
                <img src="./img/loading.gif" id="image3" width="25px"><img src="./img/tick small2.gif" id="saving2" width="25px"><span id="P3">Creating Output</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Most likely scenario, it takes time to download the image.

Comment: its 4kb file...just width of 30px*30px. Also this is on local server.

Comment: How long does `eel.process2()` take?

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell that. Eel of first process takes 8 seconds. process 2 only takes 2 secs. but process 3 also takes only 1 sec (but there is no issue)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the delay in downloading your `tick.gif`. To get around that, you could add the image as a hidden `<img \>` element on your site or preload the image using JavaScript.

```
(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = './img/tick.gif';
})();
```

Comment: Please check my edit. (The image is just 4kb and I tried even with 2mb image, result was same)

Comment: Interesting. Can you add the relevant section of your HTML to the question?